# Why do we assume the discriminant to be greater than or equal to zero while calculating the range of a function?

Tags: functions, polynomials, quadratics, discriminant

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment, I am asking [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1768078/1067190) again.

I cannot understand why we can assume that the quadratic has real roots and then say $D\ge0$. The answer states that $b^2 - 4ac = (b + 2ax)^2$ and since this is a squared term it satisfies for all $x$ belonging to $\mathbb R$. But that is the question we began with, how do we know that $x$ is real. Plugging a non-real value of $x$ does not satisfy the relation of $D$.

Comment: You don’t *assume* that the quadratic has real roots. You check *for which $y$* will the quadratic have the real root. If for some $y$ we have $D\ge 0$ ($D$ depends on $y$), the quadratic has a real root, i.e. there exists a solution $x$ that satisfies the quadratic. But then, the same $x$ satisfies $f(x)=y$ so $y$ is in range. Conversely, if $D<0$ then there is no $x$ to satisfy the quadratic, i.e. there does not exist $x$ such that $f(x)=y$, i.e. $y$ is not in the range. Altogether: $y$ is in range *if and only if* $D\ge 0$.

Comment: (Remember the definition of the *range* of function: $y$ is in the range of $f$, *by definition*, if there exists $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x)=y$.)

Comment: "*how do we know that $x$ is real*" $\,$ Granted, the linked question could have been worded better, but the assumption there is that $\,f\,$ is considered as a *real* function $\,f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R\,$ ("*for real values of y, the given equation has real roots*"). Therefore, the $\,x\,$ must be real. The same question for a *complex* function $\,f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C\,$ would require a different solution, and the final answer would be different.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you for the explanation! I think I understand, will need some time to grasp this though

Comment: Thank you !!   Ryang