# How to find the range of values for the function $f(x) = 1/x + 4/(1-x)$

Tags: functions

I know that the domain is $(0,1)$ since $x$ can't be $0$ or $1$.
But I have tried to solve the range of this function without any success.

Can anyone please show me how I should think when solving a problem like this?

Thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414298/range-of-a-rational-function

Comment: Is it given that the domain is $(0,1) $?

Comment: Because in that case you can easily apply Titu's lemma to get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In these types of questions it helps to analyze the function separately for disjoint intervals of the domain. Clearly, $x\ne0,1$ so the domain is $\Bbb R\setminus\{0,1\}$. That is to say, $x$ takes any real value but $0,1$.

For $x\in(-\infty,0)$, the function is continuous and differentiable. We need to find the minimum and maximum of $f$ in this interval, so equate the first derivative to $0$. This gives$$\frac1{x^2}=\frac4{(1-x)^2}\implies x=1/3,-1$$The point of interest is $-1$ at which $f$ obtains its maximum value of $1$ on $(-\infty,0)$. There is no minimum since $f(x)\to-\infty$ as $x\to0^-$.

Similarly analyze the function over $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$. For the former, $f$ takes minimum value of $9$ at $x=1/3$ but no maximum exists since $f\to\infty$ as $x\to0^+$. For $(1,\infty)$, there is no minimum or maximum since $f\in(-\infty,0)$. Your range is the union$$(-\infty,1]\cup[9,\infty)\cup(-\infty,0)=(-\infty,1]\cup[9,\infty)=\Bbb R\setminus(1,9)$$

Answer (score 1):

For the case of real numbers, the range comes out to be as shown in the image :

[image]

As said in the comments section earlier, if $0 <x <1$, then you can directly apply Titu's lemma to get the answer as shown:

$1/x + 4/(1-x) \geq (1+2)^2 =9$

Comment: +1 Just wanted to say, it's preferable if you can format your answers with MathJax, without putting it into pictures. You seem capable of using MathJax, but here are a couple of tips: `\implies` gives $\implies$, `\therefore` gives $\therefore$, `\cup` give $\cup$, and `\mathrm{Range} = ` gives $\mathrm{Range} = $.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be given by
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{4}{1-x}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
$$

The domain of $f$ is the set of all real numbers other than $0$ or $1$.

To find the range of $f$ set
$$
y=\frac{1}{x} + \frac{4}{1-x}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;
$$
and solve for $x$ in terms of $y$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&y=\frac{1}{x} + \frac{4}{1-x}\\[4pt]
\iff\;&yx^2+(3-y)x+1=0\;\;\text{and}\;\;x\not\in\{0,1\}\\[4pt]
\iff\;&yx^2+(3-y)x+1=0\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
\left(y=0\;\,\text{and}\;\,x=-{\small{\frac{1}{3}}}\right)
\;\;\text{or}\;\;
\left(
y\ne 0
\;\,\text{and}\;\,
x=\frac
{(y-3)\pm\sqrt{y^2-10y+9}}{2y}
\right)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence the only restriction on $y$ is the inequality $y^2-10y+9\ge 0$, or equivalently, $(y-1)(y-9)\ge 0$.

It follows that the range of $f$ is $(-\infty,1]\cup [9,\infty)$.